# Converting varchar to date does not work as expected in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I am facing a particular problem in SQL Server date conversion. I have a date in this format: `YYMM`. Let's call this `Date_To_Format`.

I wrote this function to convert it to a date

```
convert(varchar, concat('01', '-', Date_To_Format % 100, '-',
        case when Date_To_Format/100 between 60 and 99 
                then concat('19', cast(Date_To_Format / 100 as varchar)) 
                else concat('20', cast(Date_To_Format/100 as varchar)) 
         end), 5)
```

Now the problem is I need to find the last date of this month. I tried to do a dateadd to add a month and then subtract a day from it. It always adds a month to the date instead of the month.

For example: I got `01-10-2017` and the `dateadd(m,1,'01-10-2017')` I get `2017-02-10 00:00:00.0.`

I just need to trick SQL Server to recognise the month instead of date. Can you please help? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Perhaps some sample data and the desired output would make this more clear. As posted this doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Keep date as date, not as varchar. If you are on SQL Server 2012 or later, try this:

```
DECLARE @Date_To_Format nvarchar(4) = '1605'

SELECT      
    BeginningOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(@Date_To_Format / 100 + IIF(@Date_To_Format / 100 BETWEEN 60 AND 99, 1900, 2000), @Date_To_Format % 100, 1),   
    EndOfMonth = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(@Date_To_Format / 100 + IIF(@Date_To_Format / 100 BETWEEN 60 AND 99, 1900, 2000), @Date_To_Format % 100 + 1, 1))
```

`DATEFROMPARTS` is available since SQL Server 2012.